# QGraphicsPixmapItem, QGraphicsItemGroup наследованные от одного класса

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

Я пишу два класса, они наследуются от `QGraphicsPixmapItem` и `QGraphicsItemGroup` и в них есть методы `hoverEvent`:

```py
class MyPixItem(QGraphicsPixmapItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QGraphicsPixmapItem, self).__init__()

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        super().hoverEnterEvent(event)
        #some todo
    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        super().hoverLeaveEvent(event)
        #some todo 
    def someSpecFuncForPixmapItem(self):
        pass

class MyGroupItem(QGraphicsItemGroup):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QGraphicsItemGroup, self).__init__()

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        super().hoverEnterEvent(event)
        #some todo
    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        super().hoverLeaveEvent(event)
        #some todo 
    def someSpecFuncForGroupItem(self):
        pass
```

Нельзя ли их как-то наследовать от одного класса, чтобы не плодить дубликаты `hoverEnterEvent` и `hoverLeaveEvent`?

Comment: Попробуйте сделать свой класс с методами hoverEnterEvent и hoverLeaveEvent. И добавьте его в предки для ваших классов, типа: `class MyPixItem(QGraphicsPixmapItem, <Ваш класс с методами>):`

Comment: Gennadiy не совсем понимаю что вас не устраивает. Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] и расскажите лучше, что вы хотите сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Если `hoverEnterEvent` и `hoverLeaveEvent` в обоих классах одинаково реализованы, то вы можете вынести их как отдельные функции и использовать их внутри класса:

```py
def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
    ...  # some todo


def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
    ...  # some todo


class MyPixItem(QGraphicsPixmapItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QGraphicsPixmapItem, self).__init__()

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        super().hoverEnterEvent(event)
        hoverEnterEvent(self, event)

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        super().hoverLeaveEvent(event)
        hoverLeaveEvent(self, event)

    def someSpecFuncForPixmapItem(self):
        pass


class MyGroupItem(QGraphicsItemGroup, MyEvents):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QGraphicsItemGroup, self).__init__()

    def hoverEnterEvent(self, event):
        super().hoverEnterEvent(event)
        hoverEnterEvent(self, event)

    def hoverLeaveEvent(self, event):
        super().hoverLeaveEvent(event)
        hoverLeaveEvent(self, event)

    def someSpecFuncForGroupItem(self):
        pass
```

Если же реализации немного разные, вы таким же образом можете вынести похожий функционал в эти функции, и оставить в классе только отличающиеся части.

Comment: @Gennadiy если вам помог этот ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте [проголосовать и отметить ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)